# I can't figure out what this pipe attached to the cold water intake of my water heater is

Tags: water, pipe, heater

I have this small pipe attached to the cold water intake of my water heater which I cannot figure out the purpose of. It goes down from the intersection pictured and right into the wall of the outside utility room where the water heater is located. I can't find any outlet for it outside, and the only place i think it could possibly drain in to, if it is a drain, is the AC drain line, located in the same area. I should mention that I have an Aqua Therm heating system, which circulates hot water from the water heater to my air handler, then back into the water heater via the cold water intake. I'm thinking this pipe could possibly be some kind of pressure or temperature release, though I don't see the installation of anything like that explicitly described in the Aqua Therm documentation I have. Does anyone have any idea what it might be? I've included some images of it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but that looks like it could be intended to be an "instant hot water" recirculation loop...

Comment: You don't see a drain; but...is there a hose bib nearby outside?

Comment: Yes....Yes there is. Dude, that might very well be it.  That would make a lot of sense. I covered up the hose bibs recently so I forgot it was even there.  I'm not home right now but that's what I'm going to check first thing.  I'll just run the water from that hose and see if I can hear/feel anything moving through that pipe.

Comment: It is in fact just a connection to the hose bib.  I feel like an idiot now.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say from that picture. Could be an overpressure relief, not the right location for an over-temperature or combined temperature/pressure unit.

Given it's an unfinished utility room level of drywalling, a quick cut for an inspection hole to see where it goes might be reasonable, followed by a rough patch or an inspection access door that you cut the hole the correct size for installing.

Or, it might just be the cold feed to a hose bib outside.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I forgot that not long ago I bought an endoscope which I might be able to get in that area.

Answer (score 1):

This description of Aqua Therm suggests that this is the return line for the heat circulator. There will be a hot water source as well into the heating unit.
https://indoortemp.com/resources/aquatherm-hvac-system
[image]

Comment: The otherwise extraneous copper pipe from the copper tee in the first picture seems more likely to be that.

Comment: Yes there is actually a flow control thing attached to the hot water coil that is inside the air handler, and that moves the hot water back into the main water supply after it has passed through the water coils.  there is a copper pipe that brings the hot water to the air handler/Aqua Therm, and another copper pipe that it flows in to after it has passed through that.

Comment: oh, the extra copper pipe actually goes to the expansion tank.  I just didn't get it in the shot.